# Place square bracket around a cross-reference

Tags: cross-referencing, brackets

Is possible to instruct LaTeX to surround all cross-references with square brackets? For example when I write a command like `some text \ref{some label}` then when compiled I would like the output to be `some text [12]` without manually placing square brackets in the LaTeX input, as though I had entered `some text [\ref{some label}]`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you want all cross-references to be surrounded by square brackets? Or just selected ones? And, do you load any cross-referencing packages (such as as `varioref`, `hyperref`, and `cleveref`)?

Answer (score 5):

The `\ref` command is a low-level LaTeX instruction, and it is modified heavily by various packages, including `hyperref` and `cleveref`. I therefore wouldn't modify `\ref` directly, mainly to avoid all kinds of unpredictable conflicts with packages that a user may load. Instead, I suggest setting up a *new* macro called, say, `\sbref` (short for "square brackets `\ref`, I suppose) that invokes `\ref`:

```
\newcommand\sbref[1]{[\ref{#1}]}
```

If all cross-references generated by `\ref` in your document should be surrounded by square brackets, simply perform a global search and replace operation in your text editor, changing `\ref` to `\sbref`.